# Caesar cipher program written in C has a bug

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, cs50, caesar-cipher

I wrote a program for cs50 that is supposed to take in an (integer) `key` (at run-time) and output a prompt for `plaintext` which will then output an encrypted version of the plaintext according to the caesar cipher function.
The program when I run it in the cs50 IDE compiles in the terminal (`make caesar`) and when I input the 'key' at run-time (e.g. `./caesar 2`) and I get the prompt [`Plaintext:` ] and for instance I put `Hello`. The output would be `[Ciphertext: 99102109109112]` instead of the expected `[Ciphertext: JGOOQ]`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Get the 'key' value at run-time (./ceasar 'key').
// key_value must be a digit/number).
// String argv[1] must be converted to int.
// Prompt user for plaintext.
// plaintext must be converted by casaer cipher to ciphertext.
// Print ciphertext.

// Declaring variables.
string plaintext;
string ciphertext;
int key_value;

// declaring the caesar cipher function (takes in an array of characters (aka string) and an int).
void caesar_cipher(char str[], int shift_value);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // check if there are two arguments at run-time and the second argument (argv[1]) is a digit.
    if (argc == 2 && isdigit(*argv[1]))
    {
        // convert string argv[s] to an int.
        key_value = atoi(argv[1]);
        // Prompt user for plaintext.
        plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");

        printf("Ciphertext: ");

        caesar_cipher(plaintext, key_value);

        // new line
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar 'key'\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

// char str[] will take in 'plaintext' and int shift_value will take in 'key'
void caesar_cipher(char str[], int shift_value)
{
    int s = 0;
    char c = str[s];

    if (c != '\0')
    {
        // iterate through every character, letter-by-letter.
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
        {
            // case for uppercase letters.
            if (isupper(c))
            {
                 printf("%i", (((plaintext[i] - 'A') + shift_value) % 
                        26) + 'Z');
            }
            // case for lowercase letters.
            else if (islower(c))
            {
                printf("%i", (((plaintext[i] - 'a') + shift_value) % 26) 
                       + 'z');
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `caesar_cipher` in a loop?

Comment: `else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'a')` ---> 
`else if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')`  z ! not a

Comment: @CGi03 `islower()` is even better...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- you output the converted characters as integers with `%i` instead of as characters with `%c`.
- the test `if (c != '\0')` is redundant: the loop will exit immediately if the string is empty.
- you must store each character into `c` inside the loop for proper operation.
- you must add `'A'` instead of `'Z'` to the shifted index. Same problem for lowercase.
- the function should perform the encryption into another string `cyphertext` instead of printing it.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Get the 'key' value at run-time (./ceasar 'key').
//     key value must be a number.
//     string argv[1] must be converted to int.
// Prompt user for plaintext.
// plaintext must be converted by caesar_cipher to ciphertext.
// Print ciphertext.

char *caesar_cipher(const char *str, int shift_value);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    string plaintext;
    string ciphertext;
    int key_value;

    // check if there are two arguments at run-time and the second argument (argv[1]) is a digit.
    if (argc == 2 && isdigit((unsigned char)*argv[1])) {
        // convert key string argv[1] to an int.
        key_value = atoi(argv[1]);
        // prompt user for plaintext.
        plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
        cyphertext = caesar_cipher(plaintext, key_value);
        printf("Ciphertext: %s\n", cyphertext);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar 'key'\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

// The caesar_cipher function:
// takes in a string and a shift value,
// allocate a new string and perform the Caesar transformation in place
// returns the new string.
char *caesar_cipher(const char *str, int shift_value) {
    char *dest = strdup(str);

    // iterate through every character, letter-by-letter.
    for (int i = 0; dest[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        unsigned char c = dest[i];
        // case for uppercase letters.
        if (isupper(c)) {
            c = 'A' + (c - 'A' + shift_value) % 26;
        } else
        if (islower(c)) {
            c = 'a' + (c - 'a' + shift_value) % 26;
        }
        dest[i] = c;
    }
    return dest;
}
```